# Fitting an SVM model in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to fit a SVM model in scikit-learn, as follows:

```
model.fit(trainFeatures, trainLabels)
```

The issue is that my `trainFeatures` size is `(127, 9, 6, 1)`, and my `trainLabels` size is `(127,2)`.

When I returned back to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), especially for `fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)`, it mentioned that:

```
X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)
y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
```

What should I do in order to make my data format suitable to `fit`?

I tried extracting specific part from the size, like saying for instance:

```
trainFeatures = (trainFeatures[0],trainFeatures[1]*trainFeatures[2])
```

thinking that would solve the issue according to the documentation, but that turned into some mess.

Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: Please add more details about the description of data. Why is the shape `(127, 9, 6, 1)`?Assuming 127 is the number of samples, what do (9,6,1) represent?  And why the target has 2 columns? Is it a multi-label problem? Or do you have one-hot encoded the classes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not working with spatially structured data (e.g. images, sounds, time series, etc.), then the order and shape of the features doesn't matter to the model.
If that is the case, then a simple reshape should do the trick:

```
model.fit(trainFeatures.reshape(127, -1), trainLabels)
```

In any case, I'd suggest you to drop the fourth dimension with `trainFeatures.squeeze()`.
If you feel that the 9 by 6 structure of the features is important, then you could try using convolutional neural networks (if each sample is, semantically, a grid), or recurrent neural networks (if each sample is a sequence of 9 steps of a 6-dimensional signal).

Cheers